# Accessing server program on local machine from Android emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, client-server

I'm running a small Java server program on my local machine using a `serversocket` listening on port `12345`.

I want to communicate with the server from android app running in android emulator. Using address `10.0.2.2` and same port I get the following Exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

I also included the following tags in my manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"
```

The emulator tries to connect to the server when a button is clicked. It works perfectly when I run the server and client program on my local machine using `localhost` as the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just hat do configure the firewall. Adding a new rule allowing incoming connections on given port and address was the way to go.